# eBook reader like Viewer for Android app

Tags: android, mysql, windev

I want to show content in my Android app that is fetching the content from a remote MySQL server.

Currently I am showing data in WebView but here I do not have any control over many aspects like retrieving as to which word is selected (by long press) and counting the number of occurrence in the loaded content, etc.

I want to show this data in a manner an eBook is shown.

I am searching for a eBook viewer for this. Can anyone suggest one to me please.

Please note I am not reading a epub or kindle format file.

Comment: Is it html content?

Comment: yes it is HTML content